# how to increase timeout for Httparty DELETE?

Tags: ruby, httparty

I see the timeout is not working properly for the Delete.
I have the following

`HTTParty.delete(url, headers: headers, timeout: 30)`

It's actually timing out after 10 seconds and I want it to wait for 30 seconds even though my program will take somewhere around 15-20 seconds.

Did anyone had this issue?
Please let me know how to go about override the default timeout.

Comment: and you're sure its your client code that is timing out after 10s and not the server side?

Comment: @CodyCaughlan Yes, it is timing out after 10 seconds. I have added the time calculation before starting the request and after it gave me a 504 gateway timeout.

Comment: A 504 error would be coming from the server. Adjusting your client timeout will not help.

Comment: @infused Do I need to increase the timeout at the server side?